# Google Appengine Cloud Storage Application Error 10

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I try to create a pdf file from a few 100 images stored on a different bucket on the same app. The job is run as a PushTask as it taks about 4mins to complete.

But 4 out of 5 times I get this error and I'm wondering if anyone can help from Google

```
Call to URLFetch failed with application error 10 for url https://label_pdf_bucket.storage.googleapis.com/labels_1410015994.pdf?upload_id=AEnB2UrjqyJ2eqdu_o3CpWrJovyWcfsMLoqS8JE5fmwVJdDtxAn7cV4hFSrVjVX6vDpyfRr9oqZ6s4tNDPa2WC2Ky8D8O27blA.
```

Answer (score 1):

GCS related error 10 usually means the file was not open for writing. If your code has properly opened the file for writing, then you could be experiencing an intermittent issue. Make sure that your code catches the error and retries via exponential backoff. Implementation examples for various languages are available at [1].

[1] - https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors